# Nodejs trouble responding with an entire array of objects. Just responds with the first element

Tags: node.js, arrays, fetch

I have this function that is supposed to return an array of objects resulting from a loop that loops a fetch call.

```
export default (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
      let hackerArr = [];
      // this fetch call gets an array of article numbers like [2334, 5435, 21889, etc..]
      fetch(req.body.url, {
          method:"GET",
          headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      // the for loop below takes the array of article numbers from above and makes a call 
      // for each article
      .then(data => {
          for (let i = 0; i < req.body.count; i++) {
              fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${data[i]}.json`, {
                  method: "GET",
                  headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/json"
                  }
              })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {
                  // here I push the JSON object thats returned into an array
                  hackerArr.push(data)
                  // for some reason, this console.log shows the completed array of objects
                  // although i would only expect to see 1 object in the array, then 2, etc.
                  console.log(hackerArr)
                  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                  // this only returns the first element (as expected)
                  res.send(JSON.stringify({ response: hackerArr })) 
              })
              .catch(err => console.log(err))
              // if i put the res.send here, i get an empty array back
          }
          // if i put the res.send here, i get an empty array back as well
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.end(JSON.stringify({ response: 'Invalid Request Method' }))
  }
}
```

When I console.log the array (albeit inside the for loop), it shows the entire array with all 30 elements.  However, when I send the response back, I only get one element.  If I move the response to outside of the for loop, i get an empty array as a response... I am puzzled as to the problem.

Comment: `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` means this is not your only function that is doing res.write or res.json or res.someResponFunction,so: show your entire route. Start with `app.get`, and show all the middleware calls that uses (as well as which ones are implicit)

Answer (score 1):

After some major refactoring and using await, i got the result I needed

```
      let hackerArr = [];
      const response = await fetch(req.body.url);
      const data = await response.json();
      // console.log(data)
      for (let i = 0; i < req.body.count; i++) {
          const articleResponse = await fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${data[i]}.json`);
          const articleData = await articleResponse.json();
          await hackerArr.push(articleData)
      }
      await hackerArr.length > 1 ? res.send(JSON.stringify({ response: hackerArr })) : null;
```

Comment: How you are using await without async